# Problem with Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb ( AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log')

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I try to run the Mask_RCNN/samples/demo.ipynb on google colab, I cannot run the function `model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)` as the error occurs as follows.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-e1ee1fab41d5> in <module>()
      1 # Create model object in inference mode.
      2 get_ipython().magic('tensorflow_version 1.14')
----> 3 model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)
      4 
      5 # Load weights trained on MS-COCO

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 258           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    259         else:
    260           raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:390 call  *
        roi_level = log2_graph(tf.sqrt(h * w) / (224.0 / tf.sqrt(image_area)))
    /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:341 log2_graph  *
        return tf.log(x) / tf.log(2.0)

    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'
```

Can you please help me in sorting it out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Tensorflow 2.X version when the Matterport version is using Tensorflow 1.X so far (even so some tf2 compatible version exist).
If you want to keep in that way you can replace all the 'tf.log' by 'tf.math.log' but also the 'tf.random_shuffle' to 'tf.random.shuffle'.

You should check the issues in the repository, the community is quite supportive and check in particular this one corrresponding to your problem: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1797.
Best of luck.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It works finally. Much appreciate for your help! Best of luck